# Question about Hardy's proof that the Riemann zeta function has infinitely many zeros on the critical line

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading [Hardy's proof](https://archive.org/details/ComptesRendusAcademieDesSciences0158/page/n1013/mode/2up?view=theater) that the Riemann zeta function has infinitely many zeros on the critical line. He uses the fact that if $k>\frac{1}{2}$ and $Re(y)>0$, then

$\frac{1}{\pi i} \int_{k-i \infty}^{k+i \infty} \Gamma(u) y^{-u} \zeta(2u) du = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{y}}-\frac{1}{\pi i} \int_{\frac{1}{4}-i \infty}^{\frac{1}{4}+i \infty} \Gamma(u) y^{-u} \zeta(2u) du$

Why is this true? This would follow from the residue theorem if the top and bottom edges of the rectangle contour had contribution tending to zero. How to prove that they do?

Comment: Do you know the asymptotic of $\Gamma$ on vertical lines? (It decreases exponentially uniformly when the abscissas are in a compact interval)

Comment: @Conrad Do you mean Stirling's formula?

Comment: yes - that implies that $|\Gamma(\sigma+it)| \sim |t|^{\sigma-1/2}e^{-\pi |t|/2}, |t| \to \infty$ which immediately shows the legitimacy of moving the integration line to the left in the OP

Comment: @Conrad What asymptotic do you use for $\zeta(2u)$?

Comment: $|\zeta(2k+2it| << |t|, 0 \le  k \le 2, |t| \ge 1$ which follows trivially from the usual approximation theorem by a Dirichlet polynomial of length $t$  (this is trivial since there are $t$ terms and each is at most $1$ in absolute value)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you! Now I've got it.

Comment: happy to be of help